# Java HttpURLConnection, Ошибка 429

Tags: java, http, get, request, httpurlconnection

Доброго времени суток, я разрабатываю парсер для предметов на торговой площадке Steam [http://abc](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730), запрашиваю данные со страницы [http://bcd](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=6200&count=100&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=asc&appid=730), перейдя по 2й ссылке можно увидеть параметр count, который не воспринимает значения более 100, а пропарсить нужно с 6250 по 9500 (относительно), соответственно загрузить данные около 32-33 раз, но проблема заключается в том, что после 20-го раза я получаю ошибку 429 (спам запросов), заметил что в браузере Mozilla Firefox (в отличии от Chrome) можно сделать значительно больше запросов, добавление заголовка User-Agent не помогло, куки одни и те же.

Собственно хочу узнать, мне лучше найти какой-либо обход ошибки 429, либо найти возможность расширить параметр count (или что-то подобное), а может вы расскажите 3й вариант решения проблемы.

С удовольствием выслушаю ваши предложения, код на всякий случай:

```
String url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start="+<<6500-9500>>+"&count=100&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=price&sort_dir=asc&appid=730";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0");

BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

while ((inputLine = breader.readLine()) != null) data.append(inputLine);
breader.close();
connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: это один запрос ии это все запросы? немного смущает эта конструкция "+<<6500-9500>>+"

Comment: Это один запрос, конструкция <<6500-9500>> для наглядности.

Comment: добавьте паузу между запросами